# ActiveMQ Artemis running multiple web consoles for broker

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I am trying to understand ActiveMQ Artemis so I installed version 2.13.0. I successfully created and ran two broker simultaneously after reading the documentation and other online resources.

I get following on console for broker 1

```
Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8161/console
```

and for broker 2

```
Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8162/console
```

Now when I sign in on one of the web console then the other one signs out automatically. I tried to search for broker names on web console but couldn't find it.

Can anyone tell me what mistake I am making or any resource to understand by myself? I have the documentation link of ActiveMQ Artemis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ActiveMQ Artemis web console store the `JSESSIONID` in a cookie with the domain scope. To sign in simultaneously on multiple ActiveMQ Artemis instances using their web consoles you need multiple isolate browser instances or a different domain for each ActiveMQ Artemis instance.

To simulate 2 different domains you could allow a new cross origin and use [xip.io](http://xip.io/) service:

Add a the following cross origin in jolokia-access.xml of the broker 1:

```
<allow-origin>*://node1.127.0.0.1.xip.io*</allow-origin>
```

Add a the following cross origin in jolokia-access.xml of the broker 2:

```
<allow-origin>*://node2.127.0.0.1.xip.io*</allow-origin>
```

Access to the broker 1 using the following address:

```
http://node1.127.0.0.1.xip.io:8161/
```

Access to the broker 2 using the following address:

```
http://node2.127.0.0.1.xip.io:8162/
```